# The IADD function in python, is telling me its an invalid syntax

Tags: python, csv

Every time i try to tell Python to use the Iadd function it is telling me there is an invalid syntax error. I'm not sure what i'm doing to cause this, please help? :)

I've tried moving my code around to try and allow for it work, and searching up information on how to fix it but i cant seem to find anything.

```
for Taxon_types in csv_dict_reader:
    int_total_count = int_total_count + 1

    if str_category not in Taxon_types.keys():

        print (Taxon_types[csv_dict_reader[str_category]] == 1) 

    else: 
        print (Taxon_types[csv_dict_reader[str_category]] += 1)


file_infile.close()
print(Taxon_types)
```

This is the error code I receive

```
File "<ipython-input-107-c0acc5958231>", line 17
    print (Taxon_types[csv_dict_reader[str_category]] += 1)
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My hope is to be able to run this function so that when python filters the data from a CSV so every time it sees a particular type of mark it counts in as a heading and every time after this it marks it next to the heading. E.G. bob 3 
Kevin 5

Answer (score 0):

Doing an in-place add inside a function call is not legal syntax:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> def f(n):print(n)
...
>>> f(i)
1
>>> f(i += 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f(i+=1)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Instead, you should perform the addition in a separate statement, then call the print function:

```
Taxon_types[csv_dict_reader[str_category]] += 1
print (Taxon_types[csv_dict_reader[str_category]])
```

It looks as if the name `Taxon_types` has two roles in your code - the name that you are using for each row in the csv and a dictionary that is being used to track the appearances of specific values.  That isn't going to work very well - perhaps you want to use separate variables, like this:

```
for row in csv_dict_reader:
    int_total_count = int_total_count + 1

    if row[str_category] not in Taxon_types.keys():

        Taxon_types[row[str_category]] = 1
        print(Taxon_types[row[str_category]]) 

    else: 
        Taxon_types[row[str_category]] += 1
        print(Taxon_types[row[str_category]])
```

Have a look at [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) - using a defaultdict here will help you to simplify the code.

Comment: Hey Snakecharmerb, thank you so much for that, coding is still a little confusing for me. I'm new and its nice to receive feedback that is going to help me become a better coder in the future. Ill defiantly apply this to my code moving forward. Thanks again.